# Python 3: How to add <p> before and after all img tags in html

Tags: python, html, regex

For the html, I need to add a p tag before and after img tabs.
Each html includes multiple images.

For example:

```
<br><img id="aimg_uhkH3" class="zoom" src="../Images/0001.jpg" border="0" alt="" width="430" height="20"><br>
foo <img id="acvdojj2" class="zoom" src="../Images/0002.jpg" width="430" height="20" border="0" alt=""> foo
```

Desired Result:

```
<br><p><img id="aimg_uhkH3" class="zoom" src="../Images/0001.jpg" border="0" alt="" width="430" height="20"><p><br>
foo <p><img id="acvdojj2" class="zoom" src="../Images/0002.jpg" width="430" height="20" border="0" alt=""><p> foo
```

I fail to get it with regex.

My Failed Code: (test_str is the html string)

```
re.sub(r'(<img.*>)','<p>\\1<p>',test_str)
```

My Failed Result:

```
<br><p><img id="aimg_uhkH3" class="zoom" src="../Images/0001.jpg" border="0" alt="" width="430" height="20"><br><p>
foo <p><img id="acvdojj2" class="zoom" src="../Images/0002.jpg" width="430" height="20" border="0" alt=""><p> foo
```

Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'(<img.*?>)','<p>\\1<p>',test_str)` Notice the `?`

Comment: HTML is a little more straightforward if you use `<foo[^>]+>` and the like.

Answer (score 1):

Your match is terminating late. Using `.*?` will make your match end at the first `>` instead of the last `>`

```
re.sub(r'(<img.*?>)','<p>\\1<p>',test_str)
```

Comment: Using regex to parse and manipulate HTML is generally bad practice.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen agreed, my answer will fail on something like `<img title=">" ...>`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen zzz